# Encountered error when using Flask-Migrate extension

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am following the tutorial in "Flask Web Development" book and as part of the tutorial I had to use the **flask db migrate** command to create the migration script. However, when i run the command i get the following error. I looked at people who had the same error but I couldn't fix my issue based on the answers given to them.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is the relevant piece of code within my python file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'this is my secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:admin@127.0.0.1:3306/flask_practice_2'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes (moving 2 of your lines below your app.config variables)

```
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'this is my secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:admin@127.0.0.1:3306/flask_practice_2'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

Comment: That does fix my first issue of my SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not being set, but I still get the error that "No changes in the schema are detected". I'm not sure why that is

Comment: Is there the possibility that there are indeed no changes? Maybe try making a temporary but obvious change (i.e. add a temp column to a model) and then try it.

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers